# Cannot enter simply form information into SQLite DB (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

So, I'm running into a fairly simple problem, where I cannot enter some simple form values into my SQLite DB (Rails).

Interestingly, the code doesn't fail - I submit the form, and am redirected successfully to the correct URL - and a record IS inserted into the DB, but the columns "`name, type and user_id`" are not filled with anything. To clarify, the columns are blank, for that new record.

If I comment out the code in the "`create`" and simply spit out the params (`render plain: params[:plan].inspect`) I do see all the correct parameters filled out, so I have a feeling there must be something wrong in the line:

```
@plan = Plan.new(params[:plan])
```

I'm really stuck here, any guidance would be much appreciated!

**The create form**

```
<h1> Create a new plan </h1>

<%= form_for :plan, url: plans_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :type %>
  </p>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**plans_controller.rb**

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @plans = Plan.all
  end

  def show
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @plan = Plan.new
  end

  def create
    #render plain: params[:plan].inspect
    params.permit!
    @plan = Plan.new(params[:plan])
    if @plan.save
      redirect_to @plan
    else
      redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => "Plan NOT Created!"
    end
  end

end
```

**The Model**

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the **plans_controller.rb**:-

```
def create
  #render plain: params[:plan].inspect
  @plan = Plan.new(plan_params)
  if @plan.save
    redirect_to @plan
  else
    redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => "Plan NOT Created!"
  end
end

private

def plan_params
  params.require(:plan).permit(:name,:type,:user_id)
end
```

Change the field name `type` as :-

```
rails g migration rename_fields_in_plans

class RenameFieldsInPlans < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :plans, :type, :plan_type
  end
end
```

Then run the command:-

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks, but same problem still.

Comment: change the `type` field name with different name, like `plan_type` or something else and then try, as `type` is used by rails for STI http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: ah, I see - it's a reserved name. do I need to change the column name in the DB or just in the form?